# Sonar jacoco coverage without running junit

Tags: junit, sonarqube, jacoco

I've following setup in my build.xml for running jacoco:

```
                    <formatter type="xml" />
                    <batchtest todir="${reports.junit.xml.dir}">
                      <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*.java" />
                      </fileset>
                    </batchtest>
          </junit>
        </jacoco:coverage>
```

But when I run this it's giving me : 
[junit] Test  FAILED

Now developers are working on fixing the junits, but I need to know if "without" running junits can I still show how much is the unit test coverage in sonar ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no you can't get coverage data without running the unit tests. However, you *can* get coverage data even if the unit tests fail. You just need to keep unit test failure from failing the build & thereby preempting the output of the coverage report.

[It looks like the default value](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) of the `<junit>` tag attribute `haltonfailure` is `off`. So either remove your `on` or turn it `off` explicitly.

Comment: I had it off earlier and I just tried right now as well. What I need to know is can sonar give me any "unit test coverage" results even if the junits are getting FAILED ?